# Enjoyhint Tutorial does not close when ESc key is pressed

Tags: javascript

i want to close the enjoyhint tutorial when ESC key is pressed. I tried

```
that.keydown(function(e) {
    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        that.hide();
        that.options.onSkipClick();
    }
});
```

But it does not close the turorial.

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post here what is "that"

Comment: It's in the enjoyhint code.Please refer below jquery.enjoyhint.js

Comment: It's in the enjoyhint code.Please refer below jquery.enjoyhint.js

                this.enjoyhint_obj = {};
                var that = this.enjoyhint_obj;
                var $that = $(this);
                var $body = $('body');
                that.options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);

                //general classes
                that.gcl = {
                    chooser: 'enjoyhint'
                };

Comment: Please find the whole library at https://github.com/xbsoftware/enjoyhint